# UITableView/UITableView Cell Index Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, if-statement

I am making a bookmarks page for my web browser and the problem is that everytime I add a new object, I have to set the properties since I created a custom cell (I must set the text of two labels) and so I need a way to only edit the newly added object...I'm familiar with indexes but not able to come up with any solutions to this problem...For example when I bookmark the first page its fine, but once I bookmark 2 pages the 2 cells are the exact same...Any Ideas?

Heres My Code:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = (CustomCell *) [nib objectAtIndex:0];

}

// Set up the cell...

     NSString *theTitle=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
NSString *currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
      cell.websiteTitle.text = theTitle;
cell.websiteURL.text = currentURL;
universalURL = currentURL;




return cell;
}
```

When setting up the cell I need to point to the newest cell!

Thank You In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach cannot work. You cannot use the cells as the store for the titles and URLs, because cells are *reused* (and because it is bad design). A table view allocates only cells for the visible rows and reuses a cell for a different row when you scroll the table view.

Instead you should store the titles and URLs in a separated *data source*, for example an `NSMutableArray *bookmarks` where each item in the array is a `NSDictionary` with "title" and "URL" keys.

To add a bookmark to your table, you just append a new entry to the array and call `reloadData` on the table view.

The `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method can then use the `bookmarks` array with the row number `indexPath.row` to fill all elements of the cell.